# Display duplicate string from rows containing multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, yii

How to get duplicate rows containing same string (`crn`) from a table & crn can contain multiple values too? I got result only for single valued crn.

I wrote a MySQL Query:

> SELECT * FROM `event_participation` 
>       WHERE `event_id`=15 AND `crn` IN (SELECT `crn` FROM `event_participation` GROUP BY `crn`  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) ORDER BY `crn`;

This query can return rows what I expect for but only for single valued `crn` as shown in second figure.

The first figure shows duplicate rows while fetching all rows from a table but my MySQl query cannot return these duplicate rows containing one of a crn **720286** as in second figure.

*Please help me to display those two rows in second figure too.*

GitHub Issue: https://github.com/ErSKS/KhEC/issues/10

[image: Sampale Image]
[image: Required Output]

Comment: you can refer this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743859/how-to-add-select2-extension-as-filter-in-cgridview-on-yii

Comment: @NikunjRathod, Thank You for you help! I am near to solution, but I still have an error: *Model and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "widget"*.

Comment: you can try with 2 Answers resolve your issue.

Comment: I'll surely post an answer after resolving this issue.